# Is connection pooling with JDBC still improving performance nowadays?

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, connection-pooling

My application is not using any form of connection pooling, I'm working directly with connections. The application does mainly short, simple queries. From the log I can see that it frequently opens and closes connections, often performing only a single select of one or a few rows in between. These take typically ~100ms (including opening and closing the connection).

There are countless articles and blog entries on how connection pooling improves application performance, but they all seem to be rather old  (5 or more years).

Does connection pooling still provide a reasonable performance benefit or had it become obsolete. I'm using SQLServer 2008 with Microsofts JDBC driver version 3.0, if that matters.

---

Results/Update: Many things happened since I have asked this question (we switches JDBC driver and lots of other stuff). At some time I did lots of refactorings and other stuff and at that apportunity also added connection pooling to that application.
With connections pooling some queries execute now faster than the log timestamp granularity can measure (less than 16ms I believe).

So in conclusion, yes connection pooling is still worth the effort if you need to connect/disconnect frequently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If 100 ms per query is fine for you, then you don't need a connection pool.  If you need queries which are less than 20 ms, reusing connections is essential.

If your driver supports its own connection pool, I suggest you use that (in case it doesn't do this for you already).  Only if you want greater control over how connections are pooled you can use an additional library (never found a good use for one myself)

Note: you need not use a pool to re-use connections.

One simple way to reuse connections is to have one persistent connection (which has appropriate thread safety guards in place)  If your queries are infrequent, this may be all you need.

If you want to be able perform queries concurrently and only have a few threads which will perform queries, you can store a connection in a ThreadLocal field.

If you want multiple connections and you have more threads which could perform a query than you want to have in connections, use a pool.

For the ThreadLocal model you can do

```
public static final ThreadLocal<Connection> CONNECTION = new ThreadLocal<Connection>() {
     public Connection initialValue() {
         LOG.info(Thread.currentThread()+": created a connection.");
         return createConnection();
     }
};
```

If you want to control how the connections are cleaned up.

```
private static final Map<Thread, Connection> connections = new ConcurrentHashMap();
public static final ThreadLocal<Connection> CONNECTION = new ThreadLocal<Connection>() {
     public Connection initialValue() {
         LOG.info(Thread.currentThread()+": created a connection.");
         Connection conn = createConnection();
         connections.put(Thread.currentThread(), conn);
         return conn;
     }
};
public static void cleanUp() {
     for(Map.Entry<Thread, Connection> entry: connections.entrySet()) {
         Thread t = entry.getKey();
         if (!t.isAlive()) {
             LOG.info(t+": closed a connection.");
             connections.remove(t);
             entry.getValue().close();
         }
     }
}
```

If you are concerned about getting a dead connection, you can override the get() of ThreadLocal to test the connection before returning.

Comment: One persistent Connection would not work, but the number of threads performing queries is limited (I think its currently set to 2xCPUS). The ThreadLocal idea could be reasonably easy to implement in my case, although it could be hard to close them properly on shutdown. At the moment I don't have pressing performance issues with the connection time, but this could change when the client is more widely in use.

Comment: How often do you shutdown threads?  Can you keep the number of threads doing this static?  If not, you can have a collection of `Map<Thread, Connection>` which is used to find connections for dead threads and close their connections.

Comment: Threads are only shut down when the service that runs the server part is restarted or terminated, that is when the JVM exits. In practice it would not kill me if I never clean those connections up, I guess. The number of threads is determined at startup, the server selects a random idle thread and has it perform whatever service is required. My only problem is that this thread pool is not maintained by my app, but some framework (which I have to be careful to touch since its used by other apps as well).

Comment: When you shutdown a server, do you explicitly close connections now? e.g. if you are in the middle of using a connection? When you close an application, all its TCP connections are closed by the OS (perhaps not as cleanly)

Comment: There are some shutdown hooks in the server that call some cleanup hooks on my code, but I can't really guarantee that *everything* is closed properly (but I can't think of anything on top of my head that isn't). It has happened however that the VM did not shut down voluntarily in the productive environment, presumably because there were still active threads that refused to terminate properly. After some odd 60 or so seconds the service wrapper then terminated the VM forcefully. We did not note any adverse effects on our database.

Comment: I have provided an example of how you can do it either way.  I hope you can see the first example is pretty simple. ;)

Comment: In addition - irrespective of latency - some RDBMS servers spend a lot of effort to get your connection set up. So even if latency is not important for each client, you will be causing your DB server some easily avoidable pain.

Answer (score 4):

It depends to some extent on the database software. Some (e.g. MySQL) have relatively lightweight connections that are quick to open. Others, like Oracle, have connections that are big honking structures with serious overhead.

In general, though, it's a good idea to use connection pooling, *especially* for quick, short, high-volume queries.  The more quickly your app contains connections, the important it becomes. This has not changed over the last few years - if anything, it's more important than ever, as applications scale up and get more complex.

If you need convincing, I suggest you do some benchmarking, with pooling and without.  If you get no performance benefit in your specific case, then maybe it's not worth the bother.